# Is there a different way to remove a class in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code

```
$(".textForm input").focus(function(){
    $(this).val("");
    $(".card").find('.'+this.id).addClass('focus');
}).blur(function(){
    $(".card").find('.'+this.id).removeClass('focus');
});
```

To add the `.focus` class when an `input box` is focused on, but whenever I click anywhere that is not the `input box` the class is removed. Is there a way that the class gets removed only when clicking on another `input box`?
I'm not sure if I asked my question correctly, Hope someone can understand me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input').on('click',function(){
    $('.focus').removeClass('focus');
    $(this).addClass('focus')
})
```

Above code make sure you remove 'focus' class from one element only when you are adding that to another element.

Comment: This worked pretty well! Can you explain a little on how we are removing the '.focus' class from itself? It kinda confuses me a little. But it work thanks.

Comment: In an event handler, `this` is set to the object the event was triggered on, so `$(this).doStuff()` does stuff to the thing you clicked.

Comment: Ooh so `this` refers to the input in this instance right? Ok thank you!

Comment: @AndresRivera `$('.focus').removeClass('focus');` means find any element with `focus` class and remove `focus` class from them. Then next line add `focus` class to current input element

Answer (score 1):

**:input** select all the inputs

```
$(":input").click(function(){

$(":input").removeClass('focus');

});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zss9M/)**

Comment: It didn't work. I removed the `.blur` and added your code there instead, but didn't work. Probably didn't do it right.

Comment: That just removes the '.focus' class but doesn't add it to the next 'input', but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You try this:

```
 $("input.textForm").focus(function(){
    $(this).val("");
    $(".card").find('.'+$(this).attr('id')).addClass('focus');
}).blur(function(){
    $(".card").find('.'+$(this).attr('id')).removeClass('focus');
});
```